# Include Drupal 7 Modules in Bootstrap 3 webpage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7, integration, drupal-modules

I'm trying to either include Drupal into Bootstrap 3, if that is possible, or include Bootstrap into Drupal, but I don't want to recreate the whole Bootstrap page, I made already, which would be the case, if I simply installed the Bootstrap module for [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) (correct me if I'm wrong)

This is really important for me (otherwise days of work will be lost). Thank you for your time!

Comment: @nickname - question is not clear. Kindly use exact Drupal terminology for Modules / Plugins / Library. Do you want include WYSIWYG editor in BOOTSTRAP 3 page ? Why ? Is it something to be available for site visitors? Please be very specific and precise in your question and its description. This is how you will get the better response from the community members.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar is it clearer now?

Comment: @Nickname - Still its not clear. Well - as Drupal has its presentation layer backed-up by a very strong THEME functionality. So in this case you can just enable BOOTSTRAP (https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) base theme and get Bootstrap associated with either pages or module layouts.